# How and where to install a headers only library?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, libraries, header-file

I like to install [*gource*](http://code.google.com/p/gource/) which [requires **libglm-dev** installed](https://github.com/acaudwell/Gource/blob/master/INSTALL) on the system. I am using Ubuntu 10.10. Maverick. The newest sources of the headers only library I found is not available for apt-get. Afaik *gource* does not allow to configure the location of the library.

Where do I have to put the source files of the library on a Linux system? I could symlink the header file of the library to some system directory which is included in the path but that is not the way one does install libraries, right?

**Sources for libglm-dev**

- http://glm.g-truc.net/
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/amd64/libglm-dev/0.9.2.0-2
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/libglm-dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's avaliable for Ubuntu 11.10 AND it's an header-only library, then you can just download and install manually the package with

```
cd /tmp
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/72511308/libglm-dev_0.9.2.0-2_all.deb
dpkg -i libglm-dev_0.9.2.0-2_all.deb
```

Answer (score 5):

`sudo apt-get install libglm-dev` worked for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer